# 406 Not Acceptable error on jQuery :remote => true link

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, http-status-codes, http-status-code-406

I am submitting a delete request through an anchor tag link, and using :remote => true to submit it via JS to use jQuery. I've done this in two other instances which are identical to this, with no problem at all. But for some reason, this one is causing problems - whenever I submit I get a 406 Not Acceptable error.

**the destroy link**

```
content_tag( :p, link_to("+#{vote.weight}", unvote_path(vote), :method => :delete, :remote => true ), :class => "chosen" )
```

**routes.rb**

```
delete "/unvote" => "votes#destroy", :as => :unvote
```

**votes_controller.rb**

```
def destroy
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:format])
    if !current_user.owns(@vote)
      flash[:alert] = "You cannot remove votes that aren't yours!"
    end
    @idea = @vote.idea
    @vote.destroy

    respond_with @vote do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to category_idea_path(@idea.category, @idea) }
    end
end
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$('#vote_buttons').append('<%= escape_javascript get_vote_buttons(@idea.category, current_user, @idea) %>');
```

That's exactly the same line that I have in **new.js.erb**, and that works fine (apart from the fact that it doesn't return exactly what I want, but it at least executes and appends correctly).

**application.js**

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend': function(xhr) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
    },
    cache: false
 });
```

And I've got that in **application.js** which should be setting the headers correctly, if I understand right.

Also, please note that the link performs its delete functionality correctly - when I refresh the page manually, the Vote has been deleted. The only problem seems to be with the content being returned by **destroy.js.erb**

Any idea why this is acting differently to my other working examples? I've been beating my head against this all day and can't figure it out.

Comment: have you checked using firebug what kind of request you're sending and getting? Also check your logs, the request you get should be something like * / *

Comment: Response Headers: Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8.    
Request Headers: Accept */*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript.   I've already kinda figured that's the problem, but I can't get it to return the right request (text/javascript), even though it does everything the same as my other delete links.

Comment: Ok, turns out that my implementation here wasn't really exactly the same as my other delete links. The problem seems to have been with the `:unvote` pathing - when I removed that, and instead used `category_idea_vote_path(etc)`, it worked. I don't know if there's a way to get it to work with a custom route, but this seems to be a case of me trying to be too clever and it coming back to bite me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have to add an :method => :delete to your destroy link? Also you probably don't want to use  new_category_idea_vote_path for generating the destroy link but instead just category_idea_vote_path

Like that:

```
content_tag( :p, link_to("+#{i}", category_idea_vote_path(category, idea, :weight => i), :remote => true, :method => :delete ), :class => "valid" )
```

See this example:

```
  link_to("Destroy", "http://www.example.com", :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?")
```

on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: Bah, sorry Stefan. I copied the wrong piece of code - what I had there originally was the new vote link, which works fine. I've updated the question with the correct destroy link, and the relevant line from routes.rb to define unvote_path. If you could take another look for me that would be much appreciated! Also note that the link performs its delete functionality perfectly - when I refresh the page manually, the Vote has been deleted correctly.